# How to add html_entity_decode to array?

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-encode

I am making a content entry with TinyMCE in codeigniter.
However the output source is like the following and does not show < and >. Instead it shows HTML enties like &lessthan; and &greaterthan;  etc.

The entry is made by admin after logged in.

Output comes from database.

I took out escape in model, but it still does the same thing.

Also I have a config setting, $config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

So I want to add html_entity_decode. But the $page_data is an array. 
The array has id, title, content and slug which is used for page item.

Could anyone tell me how to do it please?

---

Output example:

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;images/icon1.png&quot; border=&quot;0&quot;
alt=&quot;icon&quot; width=&quot;48&quot; height=&quot;48&quot; /&gt;
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

---

Model code:

```
<?php

class Pagemodel extends Model 
{
....
...

/** 
* Return an array of a page — used in the front end
*
* @access public
* @param string
* @return array
*/
function fetch($slug)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `slug` = '$slug'");
    return $query->result_array();
}


...
...

}

?>
```

Controller code:

```
function index()
{
    $page_slug = $this->uri->segment('2'); // Grab the URI segment

    if($page_slug === FALSE)
    {
        $page_slug = 'home';
    }

$page_data = $this->pages->fetch($page_slug); // Pull the page data from the database

    if($page_data === FALSE)
    {
        show_404(); // Show a 404 if no page exists
    }
    else
    {
        $this->_view('index', $page_data[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: where does the output come from? From the database? Or from your view?

Comment: Beware of suppressing the conversion; it is there for your protection.

Comment: @Natrium: It comes from database and I added the model.
@Jonathan: As I added in the original post, the entry is done after logged in, so it should be ok.

Comment: Why do you use character entity references in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly you want to pass 'html_entity_decode.' to all fields that are returned from your database. You can easily add something to your fetch function:

```
function fetch($slug)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `slug` = '$slug'");
    for($i=0; $i<$query->num_rows(); $i++)
    {
        $html_decoded[$i]['id'] = html_entity_decode($query->id);
        $html_decoded[$i]['title'] = html_entity_decode($query->title);
        $html_decoded[$i]['content'] = html_entity_decode($query->content);
        $html_decoded[$i]['slug'] = html_entity_decode($query->slug);
    }

    return  $html_decoded;
}
```

If I got your question right that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer avoid cycling on the resultset, you can use the facilities of

```
array_map()
```

and do something like this:

```
function fetch( $slug )
{
    $query = $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `slug` = '$slug'" );
    return array_map( array( $this, decodearray ), $query->result_array());
}

function decodearray( $myarray ){
    return html_entity_decode( $myarray,ENT_QUOTES );
}
```